# CSS background SVG not displayed

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this `off.svg` icon which I want to insert through css:

```
<svg height="16" width="16" >
  <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="7"  fill="red" />
</svg>
```

The css:

```
.off-btn {
    background:url(../icons/off.svg)no-repeat;
  }
```

html:

```
<span class="off-btn" title="offline">offline</span>
```

But the svg icon does not shows up.

However when I saved `off.svg` as `off.png` and changed the css to:

```
.off-btn {
    background:url(../icons/off.png)no-repeat;
  }
```

The circle shows up. I test this on Chrome browser.

What is wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` to the svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing the SVG namespace in the SVG file. If you try to load it in a browser it will tell you that.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="16" width="16" >
  <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="7"  fill="red" />
</svg>
```